# Adding a feature to this Hangman Game

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a hangman game and I am having trouble adding in a feature. I want to make it if the whole word is guessed, it will display "You guessed the word!!!", but I cant seem to find a spot to put it. This is the code
hangman's init()

script hangman
    property stdin : missing value
    property stdout : missing value
    property dict : missing value

```
on init()
    --starting up the game
    set stdin to parent's hangmanStdin's alloc()'s init()
    set stdout to parent's hangmanStdout's alloc()'s init()
    set dict to parent's hangmanDictionary's alloc()'s init()
    my mainLoop()
end init

on mainLoop()
    repeat --endless
        set option to stdin's getOptions("Lobby", "What would you like to do?", {"New Game", "Quit"})
        if option is "New Game" then
            set difficulty to stdin's getOptions("New Game", "Choose your difficulty", {"Normal", "Easy", "Hard"})
            --replace this line with an automatic word generator
            set x to parent's hangmanGame's alloc()'s initWithWordAndDifficulty(dict's getWord(), difficulty)

            if x's startgame() is false then
                return
            else
                stdout's printf("You've scored " & x's score & " points.")
            end if
            --game is over so clear it
            set x to missing value
        else
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
end mainLoop

on shouldTerminate()
    return true
end shouldTerminate


on alloc()
    copy me to x
    return x
end alloc
```

end script

script hangmanGame
    property parent : hangman

```
property wordToGuess : missing value
property maxFaults : missing value
property usedChars : missing value
property faults : missing value
property score : 0

on initWithWordAndDifficulty(theWord, theDifficulty)
    if theDifficulty = "Hard" then
        set my maxFaults to 5
    else if theDifficulty = "Normal" then
        set my maxFaults to 8
    else --easy or any other value will be handled as easy
        set my maxFaults to 10
    end if
    set my wordToGuess to theWord
    set my usedChars to {}
    set my faults to 0
    set my score to 0
    return me
end initWithWordAndDifficulty

on startgame()
    repeat --endless
        set __prompt to "Faults Left: " & maxFaults - faults & return & "The Word: " & my makeHiddenField()
        set c to parent's stdin's getChar(__prompt)
        if c = false then
            return false
        end if
        --first check if getChar did give us any result
        if length of c is not 0 then
            --check if teh character is valid
            if c is in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" then
                --check if we already checked this before
                if c is not in my usedChars then
                    set end of my usedChars to c
                    --check if player guessed wrong character
                    if c is not in wordToGuess then
                        set faults to faults + 1
                    end if
                end if
            end if
        end if
        --check if player guessed all characters of word
        if my wordGuessed() then
            set my score to ((25 * (26 / (length of my usedChars))) as integer)
            return true
        end if
        --check if player reached the max faults he's allowed to make
        if my faults = my maxFaults then
            display dialog "The word was " & quoted form of wordToGuess
            return 0
        end if
    end repeat
end startgame

on wordGuessed()
    repeat with aChar in every text item of my wordToGuess
        if aChar is not in my usedChars then
            return false
        end if
    end repeat
    return true
end wordGuessed

on makeHiddenField()
    set characterArray to {}
    repeat with aChar in every text item of my wordToGuess
        if aChar is in my usedChars then
            set end of characterArray to aChar as string
        else
            set end of characterArray to "_"
        end if
    end repeat
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
    set hiddenField to characterArray as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return hiddenField
end makeHiddenField
```

end script

script hangmanDictionary
    property parent : hangman
    property wordsPlayed : missing value
    property allWords : missing value

```
on init()
    set wordsPlayed to {}
    --try to get more words from a file for example
    set allWords to {"Hangman", "Police", "Officer", "Desktop", "Pencil", "Window", "Language", "Wealthy", "Trauma", "Spell", "Rival", "Tactical", "Thin", "Salty", "Bluish", "Falcon", "Distilery", "Ballistics", "Fumbling", "Limitless", "South", "Humble", "Foreign", "Affliction", "Retreat", "Agreeable", "Poisoner", "Flirt", "Fearsome", "Deepwater", "Bottom", "Twisted", "Morsel", "Filament", "Winter", "Contempt", "Drimys", "Grease", "Awesome", "Compulsive", "Crayon", "Prayer", "Blonde", "Backbone", "Dreamland", "Ballet", "Continuous", "Aerobatic", "Hideous", "Harmonic", "Lottery", "Encrypt", "Cable", "Aluminium", "Hunter", "National", "Hunter", "Mechanical", "Deadbeat", "Opposition", "Threat", "Decadent", "Gazelle", "Guild", "Authoritive", "Deliverance", "Severe", "Jerid", "Alarm", "Monochrome", "Cyanide", "External", "Potential", "Section", "Innocent", "Drifting", "Amnesia", "Domino", "Flimsy", "Flamethrowing", "Advocate", "Hirsute", "Brother", "Ephemeral", "Brutal", "Decade", "Drauma", "Dilemma", "Exquisite", "Glimmer", "Fugitive", "Digital", "Associate", "Ambivalent", "Ambulatory", "Apology", "Brawler", "Molecular", "Insurance", "Contractual", "Initial", "Calibration", "Heretical", "Disclosure", "Guerilla", "Dismember", "Minimal", "Altercation", "Eastern", "Integrate", "Femur", "Metallic", "Ambition", "Auxiliary", "Esoteric", "Converse", "Accepting", "Juvenile", "Efficacious", "Complex", "Imperil", "Division", "Onerous", "Astonish", "Scandalous", "Quaint", "Dominate", "Contrary", "Conspiracy", "Earthquake", "Embarrassment", "Exclude", "Ambiguous", "Captivate", "Compliance", "Migration", "Embryo", "Abandon", "Conservation", "Appreciate", "Applaud", "Pension", "Voyage", "Influence", "Consensus", "Incapable", "Economy", "Parameter", "Contrast", "Sensitive", "Meadow", "Chimney", "Familiar", "Serious", "Credibility", "Infrastructure", "Museum", "Relinquish", "Merit", "Coalition", "Retirement", "Transaction", "Official", "Composer", "Magnitude", "Committee", "Privilege", "Diamond", "Obligation", "Transition", "Jockey", "Reinforce", "Conflict", "Offensive", "Detective", "Effective", "Detector", "Abhorrent", "Fragile", "Feigned", "Addition", "Jealous", "Irritating", "Grotesque", "Hesitant", "Adaptable", "Highfalutin", "Defiant", "Ceaseless", "Aquatic", "Voracious", "Separate", "Phobic", "Scientific", "Cluttered", "Intelligent", "Garrulous", "Rhetorical", "Obtainable", "Bawdy", "Outstanding", "Synonymous", "Gleaming", "Ambitious", "Agonizing", "Fallacious", "Lamister", "Fugitive", "Individualism", "Archaic", "Paramount", "Pannose", "Pretermit", "Retorse", "Versability", "Demonomancy", "Vagile", "Reflation", "Foliate", "Guignol", "Agacerie", "Theopneustic", "Glumiferous", "Optative", "Scrivello", "Unifarious", "Ordonnance", "Dithyrambic", "Locative", "Locomotive", "Mirabilia", "Keyline", "Mellification", "Theomicrist", "Ireless", "Commonition", "Dragoon", "Webster", "Utinam", "Obumbrate", "Inceptive"}
    return me
end init

on getWord()
    set randomNr to (random number from 1 to (length of (my allWords))) as integer
    --you could do somethinh here when a word is used again
    return item randomNr of my allWords as string
end getWord
```

end script

script hangmanStdin
    property parent : hangman

```
on init()
    return me
end init

on getChar(__prompt)
    set x to display dialog __prompt buttons {"Go", "Quit"} default button "Go" default answer ""
    if button returned of x = "Quit" then
        return false
    end if

    if length of x's text returned = 0 then
        return ""
    end if

    return character 1 of x's text returned
end getChar

on getOptions(__title, __message, __options)
    return button returned of (display alert __title message __message buttons __options default button 1)
end getOptions
```

end script

script hangmanStdout
    property parent : hangman

```
on init()
    return me
end init

on printf(__message)
    display dialog __message buttons {"OK"} default button 1
end printf
```

end script

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [your other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031272), you just need to follow the flow of your script.

In the `hangmanGame` script’s `startGame()` handler, you are using the `wordGuessed()` handler to determine if the word was guessed, so the dialog can go where you are getting that result, for example:

```
if my wordGuessed() then
  display dialog "You guessed the word!!!"
  set my score to ((25 * (26 / (length of my usedChars))) as integer)
  return true
end if
```

Comment: With this program, how could i make it so it subtracts a fault with if you dont guess the word right? Also, because you are so good at helping me with this program, could you also tell me how I could add a hint box, as in like if someone types the word "hint", a random letter in the word appears, but they can only type hint once per word? If you can do this, would be most appreciative. This is my first time adding on to a script like this and am trying to make it better than it was originally and fix some bugs. Ive done some tinkering on this program but I ask the professionals for hard stuff

Comment: also one more thing is that I'm not asking for the dialog in this program to work if the letter is guessed, I was asking if you could type the whole word out and if it was correct, then it would display the dialog. Thank you for the determination to help me though.

Comment: All that can be done, but now you are looking at a bit of refactoring, for example `hangmanStdin’s getChar()` only returns a single character, and you are not exposing any of `hangmanGames` properties to the other script objects.